# How to fix "All page's view-source returns 404 screen's html" while serving Angular Universal with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I've followed this lesson (https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/) on how to deploy and Angular Universal app to Firebase Cloud functions.

Now when I'm serving the Angular app like `npm run build:ssr && cd functions && npm run build && firebase serve` everything seems to run fine with no errors.

```
=== Serving from '/Users/jopmiddelkamp/Projects/Test/firebase-test-app'...

⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist/browser
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/jopmiddelkamp/Projects/Test/firebase-test-app/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[ssr]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/firebase-test-app/us-central1/ssr).
```

But when I take a look at the source of my pages they all get resolved as the 404 page source.

So, `localhost:5000/about` shows the about page.

But, `view-source:localhost:5000/about` shows the source of the 404 page.

Now I think it goes wrong with the `localhost:500/about` page as well. That it gets rendered like the 404 at first but then the Angular client get's bootstrapped and shows the about page correctly..

What I just don't understand is why the first request shows me the 404 page.. I can imagine it has to do with the function URL which will not be found in the router. But I just don't have enough experience in Angular and Firebase yet to understand why..

Together with Google I could not find my a solution either.. Now I could have been searching for the work keywords because of my lack in experience..

Hopefully someone here could help me out with this? It'll be much appreciated!

Also, I've been able to reproduce it with a really basic new Angular Universal project.

https://github.com/jopmiddelkamp/firebase-test-app

Comment: Ever found a solution?

Comment: @Ayyash I've ended up hosting the app in Google App Engine instead of Firebase.

Comment: interesting, I ended up adding a constant local listener to port 5000, for some reason that worked

Comment: I have a same issue is there any answer?